# Computing second point of intersection on Elliptic Curve.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves

This is a problem from http://www.williamstein.org/ent/ent.pdf

> **Problem 6.2.** One rational solution to the equation $y^2=x^3-2$ is $(3,5)$. Find a rational solution with $x$ not equal to $3$ by drawing
>   the tangent line to $(3,5)$ and computing the second point of
>   intersection.

**My attempt:** So I have drawn the graph, and have points $P_1=(3,5)$ and $P_2=(3,-5)$.
I used (with uncertainty) the Elliptic Curve group law such that $\lambda=(3x_1^2+a)/(2y_1)$, and got $27/10$ for my value.

I then used the equation $Q=(\lambda^2-x_1-x_2, -\lambda x_3-v), v = y_1 - \lambda x_1, x_3 = \lambda^2 - x_1 - x_2$.

From this, I got the following: $Q=(1.29,-5)$.

The answer in the book says that $(129/100, 383/1000)$ is the correct answer.

Could anybody help me figure this out with a solution?

Did I coincidentally get $1.29$ for my $x$-coordinate?

Comment: Did you use the tangent line? You picked two points instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to. I'm stuck.

Comment: Is that not exactly what I did?

Comment: I did use the formula for P1=P2, and the answer I get is the one above.

Comment: Here's a [sagemath cell solution](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNUMEOgjAMvS_ZPyw7AY7oWLyYeDJkFw9wRkgUSSQqEsSF_b3t0GmWdK_vvXbtikkKK0u2ZYUS65KSfmi7kfHC81x8MCX74_10PgIXqGiSVRIugySyMvRV3sDFDCmhZFJAzGmVsJhN0gVKDPAWk1mMkLNojr-EAtH47sY1Nn8zKmHVd0aHvQahGZ5NPbaPDpcDOf73YiL4oeM44admd2nq6waYFGzp7db2Y1vvXoNpgjwXxUrMJ07K38bpBhqm2ERjUQCf-BOzB17aPaopyQDohfYyYCdlbpA3LBlnVQ==&lang=sage) if you want to check the compuations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a little mistake in the calculations. Point doubling requires $P_1=P_2=(3,5)$. Next find $\lambda=(3x_1^2+a)/(2y_1)=27/10.\;$ Now $\;x_3=\lambda^2-x_1-x_2=729/100-3-3=129/100\;$ and $\;y_3=\lambda(x_1-x_3)-y_1=27/10(3-129/100)-5=-383/1000.\;$ There is a sign difference because $P_3$ is the **sum** of $P_1$ and $P_2$. The second point of intersection is $(129/100,383/1000).$

You can easily check the point doubling using [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) with the following code:
$$\texttt{E=ellinit([0,0,0,0,-2]); print(ellmul(E,[3,5],2))}$$
with the resulting output
$$\texttt{[129/100,-383/1000]}$$